# Set CA bundle for requests going through HTTPS tunnel

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, http-tunneling

I'm trying to send an HTTPS request through an HTTPS tunnel. That is, **my proxy expects HTTPS for the CONNECT. It also expects a client certificate.**

I'm using [Requests' proxy features](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies).

```py
import requests

url = "https://some.external.com/endpoint"
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(
        url,
        proxies={"https": "https://proxy.host:4443"},
        # client certificates expected by proxy
        cert=(cert_path, key_path),
        verify="/home/savior/proxy-ca-bundle.pem",
    )
    with response:
        ...
```

This works, but with some limitations:

1. I can only set client certificates for the TLS connection with the proxy, not for the external endpoint.
2. The `proxy-ca-bundle.pem` only verifies the server certificates in the TLS connection with the proxy. The server certificates from the external endpoint are seemingly ignored.

Is there any way to use `requests` to address these two issues? I'd like to set a different set of CAs for the external endpoint.

I also tried using `http.client` and [`HTTPSConnection.set_tunnel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.set_tunnel) but, as far as I can tell, its tunnel is done through HTTP and I need HTTPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it doesn't seem like `requests` currently supports this "TLS in TLS", ie. providing two sets of clients/CA bundles for a proxied requests.

We can use [PycURL](http://pycurl.io/) which simply wraps libcurl

```py
from io import BytesIO

import pycurl    

url = "https://some.external.com/endpoint"
buffer = BytesIO()

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(curl.URL, url)
curl.setopt(curl.WRITEDATA, buffer)
# proxy settings
curl.setopt(curl.HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1)
curl.setopt(curl.PROXY, "https://proxy.host")
curl.setopt(curl.PROXYPORT, 4443)
curl.setopt(curl.PROXY_SSLCERT, cert_path)
curl.setopt(curl.PROXY_SSLKEY, key_path)
curl.setopt(curl.PROXY_CAINFO, "/home/savior/proxy-ca-bundle.pem")
# endpoint verification
curl.setopt(curl.CAINFO, "/home/savior/external-ca-bundle.pem")

try:
    curl.perform()
except pycurl.error:
    pass # log or re-raise
else:
    status_code = curl.getinfo(curl.RESPONSE_CODE)
```

PycURL will use the `PROXY_` settings to establish a TLS connection to the proxy, send it an HTTP CONNECT request. Then it'll establish a new TLS session through the proxy connection to the external endpoint and use the `CAINFO` bundle to verify those server certificates.